# Should use of java.net.HttpURLConnection be discouraged as org.apache.http.client.HttpClient is way better ?

Tags: java, http, httpurlconnection, apache-httpclient-4.x

I still see people use HttpURLConnection for communicating with the websites. This forum also have many issues related to HttpURLConnection. Now, HttpClient from apache can achieve almost everything which HttpURLConnection can, with lot lesser, cleaner and efficient code. My question is,

1. As developer, should we discourage the use of HttpURLConnection in general ?
2. Are there any use cases wherein, the use of HttpURLConnection  should be preferred over HttpClient ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ***As developer, should we discourage the use of HttpURLConnection in general ?***

No, I wouldn't see it like that.

> ***Are there any use cases wherein, the use of HttpURLConnection should be preferred over HttpClient ?***

For really simple use cases where `HttpURLConnection` does the job well enough, I wouldn't include any dependency for the sake of a few lines of clearer code.

For any other situation I'd say, use `HttpClient` :-)

---

This reasoning holds for all 3rd party Java libraries. If it's a limited scenario and if the standard API does the job well enough, go with it. Otherwise, always use libraries that make your life easier. Compare for instance

- `Caldenar` / `Date` vs JodaTime
- The standard API `Collection` classes vs Guava / Apache Commons
- Library of your choice vs Standard Java counterpart.

Answer (score 2):

If you have full power of the source code, you should prefer HttpClient. It is way better than HttpURLConnection, offers more functionality and caters for things like redirects for you.

For very simple cases, it may be an overhead to use it. Also there might be a situation, where you aren't allowed to use a third-party library. These are the only reasons I can think of for not preferring HttpClient.